# What does group by do exactly ?

Tags: mysql, group-by

From an example taken from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/mysql-group-by.shtml) , I'm trying to understand what does `GROUP BY` do exactly :

Given this `employee` table :

```
+-------+----------+--------+------------+
| Empid | Empname  | Salary | DOB        |
+-------+----------+--------+------------+
| 1     | Habib    | 2014   | 2004-12-02 |
| 2     | Karan    | 4021   | 2003-04-11 |
| 3     | Samia    | 22     | 2008-02-23 |
| 4     | Hui Ling | 25     | 2008-10-15 |
| 5     | Yumie    | 29     | 1999-01-26 |
+-------+----------+--------+------------+
```

After executing `mysql> select * from employee group by empname;`

We get :

```
+-------+----------+--------+------------+
| Empid | Empname  | Salary | DOB        |
+-------+----------+--------+------------+
| 1     | Habib    | 2014   | 2004-12-02 |
| 4     | Hui Ling | 25     | 2008-10-15 |
| 2     | Karan    | 4021   | 2003-04-11 |
| 3     | Samia    | 22     | 2008-02-23 |
| 5     | Yumie    | 29     | 1999-01-26 |
+-------+----------+--------+------------+
```

So , does that mean that GROUP BY just sorts a table by key ?

Thanks

Comment: Try again with a table that contains duplicate entries in Empname. Running an aggregate function over "groups" that have exactly 1 entry each doesn't make so much sense really. It makes sense when you have e.g. 3 entries with Samia and 5 entries with Karan.

Comment: And to reply at your last question: no, group by does not guarantee a sorting - you still need to add an ORDER BY clause to enforce a certain sorting.

Comment: @CyberDem0n Right, that's the first place I looked. But that page doesn't describe what GROUP BY does, only what effect various functions have. Ultimately unhelpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GROUP BY enables summaries.  Specifically, it controls the use of summary functions like COUNT(), SUM(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX() etc. There isn't much to summarize in your example.

But, suppose you had a Deptname column. Then you could issue this query and get the average salary by Deptname.

```
SELECT AVG(Salary) Average,
       Deptname
  FROM Employee
 GROUP BY Deptname
 ORDER BY Deptname
```

If you want your result set put in a certain order, use ORDER BY.