# CakePHP GroupBy displaying all rows in a structured format

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Following is the `Banking` MySQL table structure:

```
id | name | type
1  | abc  | xyz
2  | jkl  | xyz
3  | efg  | pql
```

Right now the records are displayed in the following format:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Banking] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => abc
                        [type] => xyz
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Banking] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => jkl
                        [type] => xyz
                    )

            )
       [2] => Array
            (
                [Banking] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [name] => efg
                        [type] => pql
                    )

            )
    )
```

I need to GroupBy fields according to `type` field and display all records. Following is the desired structure:

```
    Array
    (
        [xyz] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => abc
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => jkl
                    )

            )

        [pql] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => efg
                        [type] => xyz
                    )

            )

    )
```

I tried Grouping it the following way but didn't work since GroupBy shows only one record per `type`.

```
$bankList = $this -> Banking -> find('all', array(
            'order' => 'Banking.name asc',
            'fields' => array(
                'Banking.id',
                'Banking.name',
                'Banking.type'
            ),
            'group' => array('Banking.type')
        ));
```

Though I achieved the result customizing `$bankList`:

```
foreach ($bankList as $b) {
            if (!in_array($b['Banking']['type'], $type)) {
                $type[] = $b['Banking']['type'];
            }

            $bList[$b['Banking']['type']][] = array(
                'name' => $b['Banking']['name'],
                'id' => $b['Banking']['id']
            );
        }
```

but wondering if its possible with a Query only?

Comment: you should use order by

Answer (score 0):

> I tried Grouping it the following way but didn't work since GroupBy
>   shows only one record per type.

You might want to learn SQL first, because this is the expected behaviour of `GROUP BY`, see [What does group by do exactly ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986321/what-does-group-by-do-exactly)

The resulting array structure you get is the standard CakePHP structure and has *nothing* at all to do with the SQL itself. It is just how CakePHP formats them.

Use the [Model::afterFind()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Model.html#_afterFind) callback to modify the result as you need. Create a new method like `transformResult()` and pass your data through it in afterFind().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I mentioned, GroupBy sums up the records and want to know if it is possible to change the default behaviour of GroupBy to display all fields in a nested format. OR any other optimal way to achieve the results with a SQL query so that I don't have to restructure it again with custom methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired structure by manipulating data after you fetched it from a database. In CakePHP you can use a [groupBy](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::groupBy) method:

```
$bankList = $this -> Banking -> find('all', array(
        'order' => 'Banking.name asc',
        'fields' => array(
            'Banking.id',
            'Banking.name',
            'Banking.type'
        )
    )) -> groupBy('type');
```

Please note, that it has nothing to do with SQL queries! It is just a convenient way to do same data restructuring as your code.