# Selecting Max Value and Key mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is probably a very simple fix, but I cannot get my mind wrapped around it.

I have a table factproductsales that has sales for all transactions. I have to find which product has the highest sales. I have to give the productID and the amount.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT productid, MAX(salestotalcost) 
FROM factproductsales
```

It gives me the right amount, but it gives me the wrong productid. It should be 5 but instead gives me 1. I think the mistake I am making is a very obvious one. Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does group by do exactly ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986321/what-does-group-by-do-exactly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT productid, MAX(salestotalcost) as max_cost FROM factproductsales group by productid order by max_cost desc limit 5;
```

Use [Group By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), order by and limit 5 to find max `saletotalcost`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT productid, MAX(salestotalcost) as max
FROM factproductsales GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY max DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This gives me all of the max  salestotalcost for each productID, while I only need the top value. Thank you for the help

Comment: I've added ORDER and LIMIT